# Round up the DateTime to next Day in T-SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql, datetime

I have a Date which I would like to round up to next day.

**For example**:

```
SomeDate DATETIME,
NewDate DATETIME

SomeDate = '01/05/2012 8:00:0 PM'
NewDate = Get the next day value here (in this sample it would be '01/05/2012 8:00:0 PM' + 4 Hours which is '02/05/2012 00:00:00 AM')
```

**So in simple words, What I want is:**

```
NewDate = '02/05/2012 00:00:00 AM'
```

Any quick way?

Thanks!

Comment: Is 1 ms sufficient to go to tomorrow? Is 1nano-sec? Is 1 pico-sec?

Comment: Time travel is fast these days with SQL.;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This should work:

```
SELECT DATEADD(Day, DATEDIFF(Day, 0, SYSDATETIME()), 1)
```

Answer (score 3):

To always get the next day you can do:

```
SELECT DATEADD(day, 1, CAST(@date As Date))
```

If you want to "round" the `DateTime` value to the closest whole day you can do:

```
SELECT 
   CASE WHEN CAST(@date As Time) < '12:00' THEN 
       CAST(@date As Date) 
   ELSE 
       DATEADD(day, 1, CAST(@date As Date))
   END
```

Comment: One more way to do it. Works fine. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

NextDay

```
Select DateAdd(day, Datediff(day, 0, getdate()) +1, 0)
```

Month From Today:

```
Select Dateadd(month, 1, Dateadd(Day, Datediff(day, 0, getdate()), 0))
```

Comment: No prob, keep in mind you can use many combinations of dateadd and datediff to get many different dates dynamically.